# Is it possible to loop through html elements in VBA (getelementbyID)

Tags: vba, vbscript

I have the following HTML code:

```
<td width="10%" height="20" align="center" class="data" id="requirement0" bgColor="#eeeecc">
Text - DOCIMG

.getelementbyid("Requirement0).innertext
```

The html page displays 40 requirements, so each one's ID is named requirement0, requirement1, requirement2, etc, until requirement39. I need to check if certain text is occuring inside these.  How do I loop this so that it adds one each time to the getelementbyid tag, checking the inner text for a parameter, lets say DOCIMG like above?  Is this even possible?

I tried doing:

```
For i = 0 to 39
  xxx = .getelementbyid("Requirement" & i).innertext
Next i
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: Error 91: Object Variable or With Variable not set

Comment: Then in at least one case getElementById() didn't match an element in your document.

Comment: Ok, I will double check through the ID fields, perhaps there's a space somewhere or something after the value I missed. Thanks for your help

Comment: @JasonBayldon you can only use the notation `.customMethodName("foo")` combined with the [with statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb(v=vs.80).aspx). So you need an object to perform the `getElementById()` method on, most likely a `document` object. You need to open a document using the [Internet Explorer object](http://www.excely.com/excel-vba/ie-automation.shtml). Then you can use `document.getElementById("Requirement" & i).innerHtml` to retrieve you data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up my Question, For anyone with a similar problem, I am loading from a Web Page / DB combo, and it is necessary to wait some time after the document completed event in order to access the fields populated by the DB, thats why that error kept occuring.